# Is there a variant of the "cp -a" command that avoids copying from other filesystems?

Tags: filesystems, cp, file-copy

Let's say I have a directory `/data/something` with the following subdirs:

```
/data/something/iowa
/data/something/wyoming
/data/something/burkinafaso
/data/something/slovenia
```

All four subdirs have content. `burkinafaso` and `slovenia` are mount points; `iowa` and `wyoming` are not. I want to copy the directory structure in such a way that `iowa` and `wyoming` get copied recursively with all their subtrees, but `burkinafaso` and `slovenia` are copied as empty. `cp` doesn't seem to have such a switch, unlike `du -x` and `find -xdev`. What's the best way to do what I want?

Comment: What strange system do you have where `du` has a `-x` option but `cp` doesn't?

Comment: http://letmemanpagethatforyou.com

Comment: I am sorry. I DO know how to use a manpage, but somehow managed to miss the -x switch in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a machine with the GNU Coreutils (most Linux distros), the `cp` command has `-x`.

From cp man page:

```
-x, --one-file-system
```

Answer (score 0):

`rsync` has

```
-x, --one-file-system       don't cross filesystem boundaries
```

> -x, --one-file-system
>
> This tells rsync to avoid crossing a filesystem boundary when recursing.  This does not limit the user's
>                 ability to specify items to copy from multiple filesystems, just rsync's recursion through the hierarchy
>                 of each directory that the user specified, and also the analogous recursion on the receiving side during
>                 deletion.  Also keep in mind that rsync treats a "bind" mount to the same device as being  on  the  same
>                 filesystem.
>
> If  this  option  is  repeated,  rsync  omits  all mount-point directories from the copy.  Otherwise, it
>                 includes an empty directory at each mount-point it encounters  (using  the  attributes  of  the  mounted
>                 directory because those of the underlying mount-point directory are inaccessible).
>
> If  rsync  has  been told to collapse symlinks (via --copy-links or --copy-unsafe-links), a symlink to a
>                 directory on another device is treated like a mount-point.  Symlinks to non-directories  are  unaffected
>                 by this option.

(source: man rsync)

and both source and target are allowed to be local. `rsync`s `--archive` option seems to match `cp`'s, as far as I can see, preserving pretty much everything you have permisison to preserve.